# tap gesture is not working when i touch my player( MPMovieplayerController)

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

here i try to merge all video and display that video in screen. but i need to add tap gesture when i press the player screen it should handle some action. but if i tab on view its working but if i tap on player its not working. any solution please

**EDITED:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {




 var location: CGPoint!



    var gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

    var videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        musicImg.hidden = true
        let gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture")

        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        videoPlayer.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)


    }


    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        //location = gestureRecognizer .locationInView(videoPlayer.view)
        print("tapped")
    }

    //#pragma mark - gesture delegate
    // this allows you to dispatch touches

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

        return true

    }

   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true


    }
```

Displaying my selected video in screen:

```
self.mediaUI.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        self.videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
                        self.videoPlayer.contentURL = self.videoURL


                        self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded

                        self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill

                        self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = true

                        self.videoPlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                        self.videoPlayer.fullscreen = true
                        self.videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(38, 442, 220, 106)

                        self.view.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)

                        self.videoPlayer.play()
                        self.videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

My screen in fully white, no button,label are showing

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with this...

  let gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture")

  gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;



If you want to add gesture in movie player controller


   videoPlayer.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)


and if you want for main screen...


  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)



And implement delegate methods


 #pragma mark - gesture delegate
 // this allows you to dispatch touches

  func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    return true

  }
// this enables you to handle multiple recognizers on single view
 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    return true
```

}

Comment: can u please give this solution in swift. i am not good in objective c

Comment: i am beginner . in objective c.please update your solution with swift.it will useful for mw please

Comment: i am getting error in this line ` gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;`...It says    `Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?'`.....without this line if i run means not able to tap on my player

Comment: `class ViewController: UIViewController {}`  does i need to any line for this delegate method

Comment: add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Comment: in my screen i am not able to see any label,button fully blank. see my edited post.please